# Unexpected token from webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

I got this little snippet where I call a Battlefield 3 stat server. If you visit this URL, which I'm calling, we'll be getting no errors:
http://api.bf3stats.com/pc/server/?output=json&id=534f7035-cef8-48aa-b233-8d44a0956e68

But when I try to get the stats via Ajax call, I get:

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :*

... In my console I can see that the response is coming in, as when I visit the url, but I can't get the data with the ajax call... Is there something wrong with my code???

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://api.bf3stats.com/pc/server/?output=json&id=534f7035-cef8-48aa-b233-8d44a0956e68",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but it seems like that server is reporting 500 Internal Server Error when getting it via ajax.  I've tried a number of different methods, and they all have 500 Internal Server Error returned.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I'm glad that it's not my code, but then again, I could fix my own code -- waiting for a development team to recognize and fix the issue, could take a while.

Answer (score 0):

That site seem to be unresponsive at certain times. Interesting also that the JSONP datatype did not work in Firefox. I've added a simple check to the response here.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://api.bf3stats.com/pc/server/?output=json&id=534f7035-cef8-48aa-b233-8d44a0956e68",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            if (response == null) {
                alert ("An error has occurred!");
            } else {
                console.log(response);
            }
        }
    });
}
```